# Failed to set iTunes track properties using Powershell

Tags: powershell, itunes

I used to use vbscripts to automate tasks such as adding mp3, changing genre, comments for tracks in iTunes.

I am now trying to create powershell scripts to do the same. I can added mp3 to iTunes, but I failed to change the properties of the track.... I don't know what I've missed.... The following is a sample of the powershell codes to change the Genre and the error said the property "genre" does not exist.

```
$iTunes = New-Object -com "iTunes.Application"
$library = $iTunes.LibraryPlaylist
$iTrack = $library.addfile("c:\temp\test.mp3")
$iTrack.tracks.Genre = "test"
```

However, I can see the property using `$iTrack.tracks | get-member`

```
Genre              Property   string Genre () {get} {set}
```

Thanks to anyone who could help..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found two ways (there's more) to set properties.

1. Force the track to an array and set the properties of the first item

   @($iTrack.Tracks)[0].Genre = "test"
2. Set properties by item name (which is kind of occurred when the object you have is already the one you want to set)

   $iTrack.Tracks.ItemByName('song name').Genre = "test"

Comment: Excellent! It works!  Thank you very much.  May I know why do we need to use @ to specify the track?  I actually tried ($iTrack.tracks)[0].Genre but that didn't work.  Thanks again.

Comment: @(...) is a shortcut syntax to cast the output to an array.

Comment: Appreciate your help.  This is a good learning experience for me. :)